# Create SQL Server CREATE ASSEMBLY script automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When I use SSMS to create an assembly dll, it generates a script like this :

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [SqlFunctions]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A9...
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

To generate this script automatically, I must generate the `FROM 0x4D5A9...` part, is it the hex dump of the dll ?

Is it possible using an SQL function or should I generate this hex dump with a c# function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no SQL function. You can create it using some C# like this:

```
Assembly clrAssembly = ...;
const string createTemplate = @"CREATE ASSEMBLY [{0}] AUTHORIZATION [dbo] FROM 0x{1};";

var bytes = new StringBuilder();
using (var dll = File.OpenRead(clrAssembly.Location))
{
int @byte;
while ((@byte = dll.ReadByte()) >= 0)
    bytes.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", @byte);
}

var sql = string.Format(createTemplate, clrAssembly.GetName().Name, bytes);
```